# How to create a secure module policy in SElinux

Tags: selinux, thunderbird

I am working on creating an SELinux module for a Thunderbird mail application, and I would appreciate some guidance.

The application, when installed, places various files and directories in specific locations:

- /usr/bin/thunderbird: the executable binary file
- /usr/lib/thunderbird..so: libraries installed by this application
- /usr/lib/thunderbird/plugins/.+: plugins loadable by this application installed by the administrator

---

Upon launching, the application utilizes the *~/.thunderbird/* directory, which includes:

- ~/.thunderbird/mail/: a folder containing mails, with
  a subfolder per account
- ~/.thunderbird/account.ini: account settings, including passwords
- ~/.thunderbird/plugins.txt: a list of plugins to load at startup
- ~/.thunderbird/plugins/: plugins installed by the user
- ~/.thunderbird/tmp/: temporary data

---

I need assistance in writing an SELinux module for this application.

Specifically, I want to restrict the installation of plugins to only the administrator (root), allowing the user "toto" limited access. Here are the context details:

- User "toto": user_u: user_r:_user_t
- Administrator (root): root: staff_r:_staff_t

I want to ensure that only the administrator can install plugins for all users. Any insights or examples on how to achieve this in SELinux would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!